# How to non-destructively test unknown LED strip?

Tags: power-supply, led, test

I have a tiny LED strip that I took out of a smashed LCD in my Digital camera. I remember lighting up the strip in the past but can't remember how.

I have been trying now with my bench supply to power it up but can't get it to light, I'v gone as high as 3.7 volts with no lighting, I fear I may have already destroyed it, but if I havn't how do I go about testing it without blowing the LEDs?

Image to indicate scale and layout, dots on paper are 2mm spaced:
[image]

Comment: What were these LEDs originally intended to display?  Are they segments of a 7-segment display, a bar graph, a bunch of individual point indicators, ... ?

Comment: They are the Back-light strip from the LCD. Apologies, I thought that was clear in my question.

Comment: Oh, in that case they could all be wired in series and driven from a switcher on demand.  Your newly added picture also suggests this.

Comment: @Olin: Switcher? Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: They could have the LED strip permanently connected to the output of a boost switcher.  The normal battery voltage is too little to make the diodes conduct, so turning on the LEDs is simply pulsing the switcher.

Comment: I see, well, following your responses, I took it up to 17V at which point the LEDs all lit, albeit dimly, by 18V they were approaching "bright". The final question now I guess is how high/bright can I safely drive them do we think?

Comment: Don't drive LEDs with a low impedance voltage source.  If you are using a variable voltage supply, put a resistor in series to give you better control over the current.  It's hard to say what current these LEDs are rated for, but most likely at least a few mA.  Try 3 to 5 mA and see how bright they are.  Since these were in a battery operated device, they are probably pretty high efficiency.

Comment: I agree with Olin. They'll have driven them at as bright as needed and as dim as possible. That said, most modern LEDs are 20 mA rated or higher. There are exceptions. Vf is a moderate indicator. With 7 LEDs at 18V =~ 2.6V/LED you are at the very bottom of likely Vf for blue (and White phosphor LEDs use blue LEDs.) I'd stop at 2.9V/LED or 20 mA whichever came first BUT running at well below 20 mA would be wiser. White LEDs can have Vfs of 3.5V or even more. Older LEDs tend to have higher Vfs.

Comment: Thanks, I ran them at 18V for a few seconds with a 1k series resistor which puts the current at .. 18mA(?). They seem to be happy enough at that stage, I need to look at a component that will do this switching for me that Olin mentions, I'm not planning to run 18V in a systems that runs of 5V rails.

Comment: Usually a display like this would be pulsed for current control, and that could be combined with a boost converter (which is a pulsed device anyway).  To determine your current, measure the voltage drop across the series resistor, not the voltage across the power supply.  Actually, some kinds of pulse-current controlled drivers use a small sense resistor between the load and ground and monitor the voltage on that to determine the current they are sourcing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that all my comments below, and olin's ones, assume a single LED or 2 or more in parallel. If there are 2 or more in the strip then they are quite possibly in series - so multipling the values I give below by number of LEDs may be needed. You may be able to trace out the PCB track and find how many LEDs and how connected. Start witha low voltage - see below.

---

Olin's advice is usually exceedingly good technically, so I'm always wary of contradicting him, but in this case I'd be slightly wary of 5V as some LEDs **may** not like 5V reverse bias. LEDs are very prone to damage if Vreverse_max is exceeded.

other than that his method is good (of course :-) ).
 You'll be able to use a larger resistor but 1K is fine.

[Nice table of LED forward characteristics](http://www.oksolar.com/led/led_color_chart.htm) - necessarily indicative only.

If the LED was white when it lit then Vfwd_operating is probably 3V to 3.5V.
 Red then Vfwd is more like 1.8 - 2.2 V
 Orange, yellow =  similar to red
 Yellow to greenish, green = higher. Depends on technology.
 Blue - similar to white 3 - 3.5V.

So I'd start at a lower voltage - say 2.5V or less, with the 1K resistor that Olin suggested and try both polarities and then work up in say 0.5V steps.

If you get to 3.5V and see nothing then it is probably dead, but try 4V.
 At 4V with 3.5V across LED (which it almost certainly won't be at low current) you get I = V/R = (4-3.5)/1k = 0.5 mA.
 If you look closely at the LED then 0.5 mA is easily noticeable and in some cases is surprisingly bright.

---

Just about to look at some LED data sheets for reverse voltage abs max.

Cree LP377FWh1 = 5V
 Cree LP476 = 5V
 Harvatek HT-F259 = 5V at 100 uA
 Luxeon Rebel ES = Don't do it.
 Nichia NSPW500CS = 5V at 50 uA

Looks like Olin hit the typical max value exactly :-).
 ie at 5V you may well be OK.
 But, use less to start.

Comment: Thank for for the detailed response, the theory is no problem, I graduated an Electronic Engineer, but non-destructive testing has never been something I put much thought into. :D My concern here was that it's so small I don't have visible connections to look at how it's wired. From my testing so far it seems they're wired in series, which makes sense. ~3V appears to be the operating voltage of each LED, but with 7 of them in the strip, I can't imagine the requirement to be 7x3V?! Maybe a photo in the original question would help to demonstrate how small we're talking.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer, and apologise to Olin, only because a beginner, not aware of the polarity problem could have destroyed it using Olin's method. Fortunately I had already figured the polarity (because I soldered wires to it when I first messed with it, as in the picture).

Answer (score 2):

I would use a 5V power supply with maybe a 1 kΩ resistor in series and start probing pairs of pins.  The smallest likely forward drop accross a LED is 1.8V, which would put a bit over 3 mA thru it.  Neither 5 V nor 3 mA should damage the LEDs, but that should be enough current to see them light up if you're doing this in normal office lighting.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Because of the small size, there is only one "pad" between each LED that I can touch onto, I don't have pairs of legs, so, here's what I did, 1K resistor on ground, 3V, then touched he positive onto each of the pads in turn, last 2 LEDs lit very dimly, last 1 LED when touching onto its pad lit full brightness. Up to 6V, touched the second LED from end, and last 2 light full brightness. Question it, where do I go from here, surely I can't need to add 3V for each LED? (There are 7).

Comment: @Hamid: Things get complicated when the LEDs are in series.  Continue probing different combinations of pins in both polarities.  Maybe the rest aren't all wired in series.  It would surprising if the camera generated 20V to light all the LEDs.

Comment: My thoughts exactly, but even as high as 5V on the terminals doesn't light any of the LEDs at all, yet I can get the last couple lit with 3V each, 6V across the two, I don't want to keep going higher and moving along the line.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use a constant current source such as the LM317, 5-10mA setting should do fine then just measure the output voltage. Most DMM's should be able to measure the Vf.